# Why does a class inhering another class not produce the same results as 'another class'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I am developing an application in Python using PyQt5. Here is the code in question:

```py
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.main.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setStyleSheet(QMainWindowStyle)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main)
        self.show()

class AppearanceTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class SettingsDialog(Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabs.setStyleSheet(QTabWidgetStyle)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)

        self.tab_appearance = AppearanceTab()
        self.tab_appearance.setStyleSheet(QWidgetStyle)
        self.tab_appearance_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.tab_appearance.setLayout(self.tab_appearance_layout)
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab_appearance, "Appearance")

        self.tab_server = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_server.setStyleSheet(QWidgetStyle)
        self.tab_server_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.tab_server.setLayout(self.tab_server_layout)
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab_server, "Server")
```

Why is it that when `self.tab_appearance` is an `AppearanceTab` instance (which *should* be a copy of `QWidget`) it has a different style to `self.tab_server` (i.e. background colour changes) when `self.tab_server` is an instance of `QWidget`?

The stylesheet just defines `background-color: #333333` and `color: #dddddd`.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I believe that the stylesheet is not being properly applied to `AppearanceTab`, however I don;t know why that would be seeing as it just inherits from `QWidget`.

EDIT 2:

A MCVE (along with the rest of my project) can be found [on github](https://github.com/Jachdich/lime-ide/blob/master/Minimal%20Example%20(for%20SO).py).

Comment: Could you please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the css stylesheet?

Comment: Yes I will try however it'll be a while (lots of code to trim/I'm currently in school)

Comment: @JacquesGaudin see my recent edit for the MCVE (and also the rest of my code)

Comment: thanks, I don't have QT on my machine now but I can try later. My first thought would be to change `QMainWindowStyle = QMainWindow {color: #dddddd; background-color: #333333;}` to  `QMainWindowStyle = QMainWindow, QMainWindow * {color: #dddddd; background-color: #333333;}` so that all the child widget of the main window have the same style.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin it worked, thank you! I'll accept an answer if you post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation, there is a paragraph the [paragraph about inheritance](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#inheritance) and style:

> **Inheritance**
>
> In classic CSS, when font and color of an item is not explicitly set, it gets automatically inherited from the parent. When using Qt Style Sheets, a widget does not automatically inherit its font and color setting from its parent widget.
>
> If we want to set the color on a QGroupBox and its children, we can write:
>
> ```
> qApp->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox, QGroupBox * { color: red; }");
> ```

So you probably want to  to change

```
QMainWindowStyle = QMainWindow {color: #dddddd; background-color: #333333;}
```

to

```
QMainWindowStyle = QMainWindow, QMainWindow * {color: #dddddd; background-color: #333333;}
```

so that all the child widgets of the main window have the same style.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for me. I changed `self.tab_appearance.setStyleSheet(QWidgetStyle)` to `self.tab_appearance.setStyleSheet("QWidget, QWidget * {background-color: #333333; color: #dddddd;}")` without success.

Comment: I meant to put it in the CSS. Have you tried that too?

Comment: My mistake, I think it's about child widgets not class inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.main.setLayout(self.layout)

#        self.setStyleSheet(QMainWindowStyle)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main)
        self.show()

class AppearanceTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class SettingsDialog(Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self)
#        self.tabs.setStyleSheet(QTabWidgetStyle)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)

        self.tab_appearance = AppearanceTab()
#        self.tab_appearance.setStyleSheet(QWidgetStyle)
##        self.tab_appearance.setStyleSheet("QWidget, QWidget * {color: #dddddd; background-color: #333333;}") #note: Tried this however it didn't work.
        self.tab_appearance_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.tab_appearance.setLayout(self.tab_appearance_layout)
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab_appearance, "Appearance")

        self.tab_server = QtWidgets.QWidget()
#        self.tab_server.setStyleSheet(QWidgetStyle)
        self.tab_server_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.tab_server.setLayout(self.tab_server_layout)
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab_server, "Server")



style = """
QWidget {
    color: #dddddd;
    background-color: #333333;
}

QMainWindow {
    color: #dddddd;
    background-color: #333333;
}

QTabWidget {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #dddddd;
}
QTabBar {
    color: #dddddd;
    background-color: #333333;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create("Fusion"))
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyleSheet(style)                       # < ---
    d = SettingsDialog()
    print(app.exec_())
```